# Convert a String or a InputStreamReader into InputSource

Tags: android, xml

I just read some tutorials in order to parse a xml feed from the web and turn them into a Listview:

```
URL file = new URL("http://..../file.xml"); 
SAXParserFactory fabrique = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser parseur = fabrique.newSAXParser();
XMLReader xr = parseur.getXMLReader(); 
ReglageParseur gestionnaire = new ReglageParseur();
xr.setContentHandler(gestionnaire);
xr.parse(new InputSource(file.openStream()));
```

Everything is fine and I am able to parse xml.

My second step is to store the xml file from web into a xml file on the phone and only update it when user ask it. ( In fact, this xml file should not change or maybe once every 6 month, so I don't want to download it each time.)

So, what I did is to store the file on the phone and update it on user demand.

And I can read it by doing:

```
fIn = openFileInput("fichier.xml");
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
char[] inputBuffer = new char[255];
isr.read(inputBuffer);
String readString = new String(inputBuffer);
```

So, for now, everything seem fine and I am nearly happy.

The problem is now when I want to parse the new file on the phone:

```
xr.parse(InputSource);
```

I need an InputSource as parameter.

So my question is:

How can I turn my file in the phone into a InputSource?
I succeed to have a InputStreamReader or a String but would like to convert that into InputSource.

Thank a lot for any precious help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I don't know what constructors are available on the Android version, but the [J2SE `InputSource` class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/InputSource.html) has a constructor with a `Reader` parameter. Have you tried that?

Alternatively, why not just construct an InputSource directly from the `InputStream`? I assume `fIn` is a `FileInputStream`? Why not just call:

```
InputSource input = new InputSource(fIn);
```

?

Comment: Thank a lot, I just found InputSource input = new InputSource(new StringReader(readString)); but your answer is really better!

Comment: Ouch I did really stupid stuff! Thank a lot for opening my eyes! Stupid question :-p

Answer (score 6):

the best suitable line for me to convert string to InputSource is :

```
String myStringObject = "Hello this is string object to convert in InputSource";
InputSource inSource =  new InputSource(new StringReader(myStringObject));
```